# csv files formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, csv

I have been dealing with a lot of csv files latelly and I need them to open in Excel and split correctly

I append "sep=," to the beginning of the text file and the columns get split correctly

the issue is, my language uses a lot of "special" characters like "ç" or "ã", and the formatting gets distorted if I add the beforementioned "sep=," to the file

is there any option I can add to the file so it is displayed without issues?

I am aware of the text to columns button but this is very inefficient since I am constantly doing this

Comment: I also tried adding \ufeff to the beginning of the file as some people suggested in other places and it doesn't work

Comment: There is a power query in excel method that might work well here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72210897/excel-how-to-split-cells-by-comma-delimiter-into-new-cells