# Excel Macro: How to strip currency from text with other numbrs?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Help! Trying to strip prices from a cell in Excel. Will always have either a '$' and/or a '.' in the amount.  Problems arise since 1) there can be multiple currency formats, 2) there are other numbers in cell, 3) I don't want to strip out carriage return formatting

Example Cell Content: This should strip out $159.95 and 69.95

```
90,000 Mile
Intake Service $159.95
Air Filter 69.95
Rear Brake Pads (4MM)
```

[image: Example Cell Content]

This is an easy find/replace regular expression in Notepad++, but I'm not allowed to access this at work. Does Excel have something to find '$' and remove it plus numbers after it up until the next space or carriage return?

The closest I've found is a MID or TEXTAFTER function but it also takes out all of the data after the '$' or it removes all the carriage returns.

....................

Comment: This looks really messy you have multiple lines in a single cell. If you want the end results to be the same I recommend do it in python with regex. If you want to keep it in excel split up the lines in the cell to be multiple cells.

Comment: Another option is to use Powerquery in excel here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/72210898/5091720
Part of the problem is that there maybe some cells with 5 lines of data and other cells with 2 lines of data. The excel formulas will not work in those enviroments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Microsoft 365:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(
    TEXTJOIN(
        " ",
        ,
        LET(
            a, SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(10), "~!"),
            b, TEXTSPLIT(a, , {" ", "~"}),
            c, ISNUMBER(FIND({"$", "."}, b)),
            d, BYROW(c, LAMBDA(arr, OR(arr))),
            e, FILTER(b, NOT(d)),
            e
        )
    ),
    "!",
    CHAR(10)
)
```

[image]

***Algorithm***

- Replace the line feed with `~!`

  - Enables splitting on `space` and `tilde`, leaving the `!` to replace the linefeeds when we rejoin the string
- Filter the resultant array removing substrings that contain `$` or `.`

  - Note that when `find_text` is an array, the result will be a multi-column array with one column for each element

    - We use the `BYROW` function to reduce this to a single column array for use in the `FILTER` function.
- Rejoin with spaces
- Then replace the `!` with linefeeds

---

If you do not have Microsoft 365, this can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the code and comments. The algorithm is very similar to the formula above

```
let

//Change next line to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),

    #"Remove Currency" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",

//split each cell on the line feed
// then split each split on space
// remove items that contain $ or .
// reassemble
    {"Column1", (c)=>
       try
        let 
            lines = Text.Split(c,"#(lf)"),
            removeCurr = List.Transform(lines, (d)=>
                let 
                    words = Text.Split(d," "),
                    notCurr = List.Select(words, each not Text.Contains(_,"$") and not Text.Contains(_,"."))
                in 
                    notCurr)
        in 
            Text.Combine(List.Transform(removeCurr, each Text.Combine(_," ")), "#(lf)")

        otherwise null}
    )
in
    #"Remove Currency"
```

Comment: Oh...this makes so much sense. Thanks so much, I've been banging my head against a wall for hours.

Comment: @ExcelNoob please ensure to accept the answer given by Ron Sir by ticking the checkmark beside the answer. It is a valuable solution, going forward it might help someone in future.